# KeyError when key exists in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm working on a code that detects the langue of a tweet and applies the lexical matching that language. The code USED to work just fine, it did its job. Then it threw a `KeyError: 'en'` even though 'en' exists in the dictionary. I've looked at multiple questions that already have answers and nothing in them seems to work. I'll provide the part of the code that deals with German only (so not including the other langues). The code is written to where if the language detected isn't in the dictionary, it'll automatically be classified as English.

```
from langdetect import detect
import glob
import re

rsc_lg = {
      "de" : {"pos" : "ressources/positive_words_de.txt",
              "neg" : "ressources/negative_words_de.txt"},
      "en" : {"pos" : "ressources/positive_words_en.txt",
              "neg" : "ressources/negative_words_en.txt"}
      }
dic = {}
liste_resultats = []
for path in glob.glob("corpus/*/*/*"):
  f = open(path, errors="ignore")
  read = f.read().lower()
  lang = detect(read)
  if lang not in dic:
    dic[lang] = {} 

  if lang not in rsc_lg :
    lang = "en"

###german###
  f_de_pos = open(rsc_lg[lang]["pos"])
  f_de_neg = open(rsc_lg[lang]["neg"])
  de_pos = f_de_pos.read().lower().split()
  de_neg = f_de_neg.read().lower().split()
  f_de_pos.close()
  f_de_neg.close()

  words = read.split()
  pos_words_de = set(words) & set(de_pos)
  neg_words_de = set(words) & set(de_neg)

  if len(pos_words_de) > len(neg_words_de):
      diagnostic = "positive"
  if len(pos_words_de) == len(neg_words_de):
      diagnostic = "mixed"
  if len(pos_words_de) < len(neg_words_de):
      diagnostic = "negative"
#  print("this german tweet is ", diagnostic)
  dic[lang][path] = diagnostic


  corpus, lang, classe, nom = re.split("\\\\", path)
  liste_resultats.append([nom, lang, classe, diagnostic])

import json
w = open("resultats_langdetect_german.json", "w")
w.write(json.dumps(liste_resultats, indent= 2))
w.close()

f.close()

print("done")
```

The error comes up with the line `dic[lang][path] = diagnostic` just after the classification of tweets as positive, mixed or negative.
Like I said, this worked just fine before and suddenly stopped working despite me making absolutely no changes whatsoever to the code.

Comment: did you debug this code? what line the error was thrown?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I've added where the error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is if you encounter an unknown language then you perform `dic[lang] = {}` and immediately after that you do `lang = "en"`. Now if `lang` was for example `"es"` you end up with `dic == {"es": {}}` and `lang == "en"`. Later in the code you do `dic[lang][path] = diagnostic` but at this point `"en" not in dic` since it still used the unknown language code (`"es"`). You probably want to switch the order of the two statements, i.e. first set `lang = "en"` and then do `dic[lang] = {}`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of that. Weird that it worked just fine before and suddenly realized that there was an error!

Comment: @ArieG. It's probably because you ran the code on some new data which was detected as a language that was not include in your resources. That's how it can change behavior without changing the code itself, it's dependent on input data.